# DjangoのDBを、runserverなしで利用する方法について

Tags: python3, django

Webserverを立ち上げることなく（python3 manage.py runserverすることなく）、
Djangoのデータベースの、ORマッピング機能とマイグレーション機能のみを利用したいのですが、つまずいています。
django.setup()とモデルクラスを定義する順番があるようなのですが、解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

【参考としたサイト】：https://logixsquare.com/techblog/django_models_only/

【やったこと】：
# 仮想環境の作成/アクティベート
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
# Djangoのインストール
pip3 install django
# Djangoプロジェクトの作成
mkdir helloworldproject
cd bookproject
# Djangoアプリの作成（不要？）
django-admin startproject hello
# ./アプリ名/test.pyに、以下のコードを記載

【エラー内容】
INSTALLED_APPSを変更し、モデルクラスを定義すると、以下のエラーが発生します。
'hello.tests' does not contain a 'SampleModel' class.

```
import sys

# 初期設定
sys.path.append('./helloworldproject')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from django.conf import settings
    settings.configure(
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': './db.sqlite3',
            }
        },
        # INSTALLED_APPS=['hello.tests.SampleModel'] # ←ここと、以下SampleModelクラスのコメントアウトを外すとエラーとなる。
    )

    import django
    django.setup()

    # モデル定義
    # from django.db import models
    # class SampleModel(models.Model):
    #     title = models.CharField(max_length=100) # 列タイトル
    #     number = models.IntegerField() # 列ナンバー
```

Comment: mkdir helloworldproject; cd bookproject ← ここで失敗していて、helloworldprojectがカレントになっていないだけではないですか? と思いましたがただのtypoの可能性もあるのでひとまずコメントだけ。他に 「./アプリ名/test.pyに、以下のコードを記載」もファイル名が間違っているのでは? と思いました。これも質問時のtypoでしょうか。あと、参考としたサイトを挙げていますが、完全に無視しているように見えます。参考としたサイトに書いてあることは実行して何がどう動くか把握した上で、自分のやりたいことのために変更しているのでしょうか? だとしたら「なにをしたいのか?」が質問に欠けていると思います。それが書かれていないと第三者からは「単に参考としたサイトをろくに読まずに適当に書いているだけ」みたいに見えてしまいますよ。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。

以下を追加することで、INSTALLED_APPSに'hello.apps.HelloConfig'を指定できるようになりました。

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

SampleModelクラスはmodels.pyに、記載し、makemigrations、migrateしました。

ありがとうございました。Closeします。